# Is there anyway to solve the space between first and last image when using amp-carousel of type="carousel"?

Tags: carousel, amp-html

I'm using amp-carousel "version 0.2" which allows to use autoplay and loop attributes for amp-carousel of type ="carousel"

it appears that the last and first only stacked over each other but all the carousel items are working fine

[image]

Comment: we have something similar but do not see your issue. one difference between you/us might be that we load content from `amp-list`. You should post the code for folks to inspect.

Comment: @JayGray  thanks for your response  , here is my code 
 <amp-carousel  height="300" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel" loop  autoplay delay="3000"  >     
                    <amp-img src="./assets/projects/USEO-15.jpg" width="280" height="300" alt=""></amp-img>
                    <amp-img src="./assets/projects/USEO-16.jpg" width="280" height="300" alt=""></amp-img>
                    <amp-img src="./assets/projects/USEO-17.jpg" width="280" height="300" alt=""></amp-img>


                </amp-carousel>

Comment: what happens if you use `layout=fixed` on each image? If that doesn't work, try `layout=responsive`.

Comment: same error for both layouts

Comment: hard to know without seeing all code. for example, you seem to be using captions. is it possible that your html is not properly closed? why is there a difference in the caption height?

Comment: no there aren't any caption , the image itself contains this caption
yeah i check the html many times and it is properly closed , i even try to change order of the images and removing some slides  but always sameoutput